# Can't trace an java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: java, debugging

I'm trying to solve following simple programming exercise: "Write a program that reads the integers between 1 and 10 and counts the occurrences of each. Assume the input ends with 0". I've come up with following solution. I'm not familiar with debugger and trying trace `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` last 3 hours. Maybe someone is able to see the where `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise07_03 {
    /** Main method */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] numbers = new int[10];
        System.out.print("Enter up to 10 integers between 1 and 10" + 
            "inclusive (input ends with zero): ");

        int i = 0;
        do {
            numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
            i++;
        } while (numbers[i] != 0 && i != 9);

        displayCounts(countNumbers(numbers));
    }

    /** Count the occurrences of each number */
    public static int[] countNumbers(int[] numbers) {
        int[] counts = new int[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)
            counts[numbers[i] - 1]++;

        return counts;
    }

    /** Display counts */
    public static void displayCounts(int[] counts) {
        for (int i = 1; i < counts.length + 1; i++)
            if (counts[i - 1] != 0)
                System.out.println(i + " occurs " + counts[i - 1] + " time");
    }
}
```

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException usually happens when you have "off by one" errors here and there. If you have problems with the debugger, you might as well do some print debugging in your loops and verify that your indexes are actually what you think they are at any point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
public static int[] countNumbers(int[] numbers) {
    int[] counts = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)
        counts[numbers[i] - 1]++;

    return counts;
}
```

The solution is in:

```
 counts[(number - 1 > 0) ? number - 1 : 0]++;
```

This checks if (number-1) is greater than zero. If not it uses 0. If true it uses number -1.

Comment: Guess I actually said the same thing, but a compliment does it all ;)

Comment: No. Explaining the problem does it all. I went through and told him where his problem was and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

```
         counts[numbers[i] - 1]++;
```

results -1 if input contains 0.